# Resume animateWithDuration .Repeat after return to foreground

Tags: swift, uiview, background, foreground, animatewithduration

Unfortunately, I found out that `UIView.animateWithDuration` stops once you minimize your app to homescreen and does not resume once you bring it back to the foreground.

I've spent the last hour trying to figure out how to solve this (by detecting background/foreground switching) and resulted to adding an observer. I did it and successfully detected it with a debugging message in console; however, I'm sure of how to resume the animation(s) in my view(s). What is the correct way to pause/resume or even restart the animation when the app is loaded back into the foreground?

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func cameBackFromSleep(sender : AnyObject) {
        // Restart animation here or resume?
        print ("If you can see this, congrats... observer works :-)")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Observer to detect return from background
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(    self,    selector: #selector(ViewController0.cameBackFromSleep(_:)),    name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,    object: nil    )

        // Add a label
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 600 , 200, 200 ))
        label.text = "test message"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)
        label.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        // Animation to move label
        func animateText() {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [ .Autoreverse, .Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut, .BeginFromCurrentState], animations: {
                label.alpha = 0.3
                label.frame.origin.x = ((global.maxwidth/2) * -1) 
                }, completion: { finished in
                    if finished {
                        label.frame.origin.x = 0.0
                    }
            })
        }

        // This guy here stops once you minimize the app to background
        animateText()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `animateText()` inside `comeBackFromSleep(_:)`. I believe that resuming an animation is kinda hard so just restart it.

The behavior somewhat makes sense because of this (you can take a look yourself at the `AppDelegate`'s methods):

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

It states that you should refresh the UI (which includes animations). So it's normal behavior for the animations to stop after you put an app in the background.

Comment: I'm new to Swift/iOS development.  Since `comeBackFromSleep()` is out of `viewDidLoad()`'s scope how would I call `animateText()` that's inside `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: You need to put `func animateText()` OUTSIDE `viewDidLoad()`. That way you can then access it from any other method. So put `func animateText()` below `viewDidLoad()` and type `animateText()` in `comeBackFromSleep()`.

Comment: I figured that would be the easy solution but my actual animation function does have other variables that depend on the label's width within the view once it's already initiated. It has gotten complex that I think my only solution is to somehow delete the label and add it to the view again with animation each time the application is returned to the foreground.

Comment: Declare the label as a global variable (just below where the class starts) like this: `let label = UILabel()`. Then below //Add label delete `let` and there you go. You can access the label and it's properties from anywhere in the class. And then do what I said and it should work.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Comment: Works great but if you minimize the application to the background a second time, the observer doesn't function anymore thus the animation doesn't restart.

Comment: Then every time you send it to the background you remove the observer then you add a new identical one. This should fix the issue. Try it and see what happens. Type `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)` and the line where you add a new observer in `cameBackFromSleep()`.

Comment: Excellent! I found out that the `}, completion: { finished in` portion of the animation was conflicting when you return to the application. Hope this helps someone out there. Thanks again.